# Stop only firebase push-notification vibration

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, push-notification

How to stop firebase push notification vibration while app in fore ground in objective c?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
  if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
   else {
        completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually my requirement there is option in my app to stop push vibration or sound  individually. How to achieve this one ?

Comment: Create a shared variable and replace it in if statement check above